# Permission problems when trying to test facebook sdk in laravel

Tags: php, facebook, permissions, laravel

After adding the SDK to my laravel app, i tried testing it but had this error

**

> (Error in exception handler: The stream or file
>   "/home/newdev/public_html/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be
>   opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/newdev/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:70)

**

You can visit this link to see it http://newdev.cart.com.ng

Comment: Disable your app sandbox mode. its gives This app is in sandbox mode. Edit the app configuration at http://developers.facebook.com/apps to make the app publicly visible.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in Windows. I tried giving full control permissions to user Everyone for the /storage/logs folder and it worked. Then, I removed those permissions and now its working with full control permissions just for the IIS_IUSRS group.
So, probably the account that is being used in your application server does not have permission to write or create (the first time) the laravel.log file.

Comment: Giving IUSR group full permissions to the folder did the trick for me.